# Better plotting of tree object

Tags: r

I am trying to find a better way to plot a "tree" object from the *tree* package in R. I realize that there are good plotting tools for *rpart* package trees, but I am creating my tree object from scratch, therefore a "tree" object from the *tree* package is better suited for my purposes.

My question is, does anyone know of a better way to plot "tree" objects than `plot`?

I am trying to include the distribution of values, square blocks for the leaf nodes, majority class, etc.

I could've sworn there was a package that could take a "tree" object as the argument but I can't seem to find it.

This is for a classification tree.

Comment: `draw.tree()` in `maptree` package can take a `"tree"` object. I feel its output is better than `plot()`, but a little...

Comment: Perhaps you can reuse the `fancyRpartPlot` function from rattle?